# Updating an Ender 3 V2

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware

I recently got an Ender 3 V2 and when I go to Info -> Version it says V1.0.0. [However online, there is V1.0.1 available.](https://www.creality.com/download/)

How can I update the Ender 3 V2. It is different as it isn't a ATMEL chip like the ATMEGA 2560 but rather an ARM processor. I own many arduino boards but apparently the chip has the bootloader already on it.

So how can I update the board, through some uploader, specific software or what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the firmware to a blank microsd card.
Turn off the printer and turn it on.
Board will flash it automatically and wait the screen to up.

Make sure the name of the firmware file always unique or different from the last one, otherwise you will get the blank screen.
If you do, just re-flash by using a rename (different) file of firmware.

Comment: thank you very much, CHEP on youtube just made a video about it showing your method. Putting it on a micro SD card should work the next time I need to update and it so much easier than plugging it in

Answer (score 1):

After looking around for a bit in Cura. You can update it via Cura.

Start by going to your printer -> Manage printer

Then there is the option to update firmware. You must plug the printer in first.